# How do I knit to a html in r, with this error?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to knit to a html in r for my uni assignment and it won't work. 
The code "count" works but apparently 'could not be found' - says the error.

This is the issue in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: You need to library the package of the function `count()` in the code chunk before you use it.

Comment: how do I do that? I tried library(count) it didn't work

Comment: I did it! Thank you!! library(ply)